# Review page bug - link to questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

The original issue (english.stackexchange): [Can't close the "share a link to this question" popup on review page](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2143/11762).

I checked to see if this would repro on StackOverflow, and got a slightly differnet bug.

The first post I upvoted did not create a link popup. The second one created a link popup for both the first and second, and I was only able to close one of them.

Comment: The popup doesn't appear all times you up-vote a question; it appears randomly, for specific questions.

Comment: @kiamlaluno In the StackOverflow case, it appeared at the same time for two different questions, but not until I voted on the second one. At that point, I was only able to close one.

Comment: tricky tricky tricky ... will look at a fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed this one, moving question from #question to .question left a fair bit of changes to much of our JavaScript ...