# Review page - flag or close

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

Possibly related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112798/167443) regarding linking questions from the /review page, when flagging a post or voting to close a question on the /review page, if more than one post is opened for review, the dialog for flagging/voting to close does not close one the action is submitted (although the action does submit). However, it closes properly when the X in the corner is clicked.

I've encountered this bug using IE8 on the /review pages of both StackOverflow and english.stackexchange.

Possibly related to [this issue](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2066/11762)?

Comment: I have the same problem in IE9.

Comment: I also have this problem in Firefox 3.6

Comment: wait, is this still the case?

Comment: If I can find a post worth flagging, I will let you know

Comment: @waffles Just tried it with close-voting a question on english.SE, and it worked fine. Didn't see anything worth flagging on SO though, so that is unconfirmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking this as fixed, I am pretty sure we sorted this out a while back